# Framework for REST API design for large data set

Tags: python, json, node.js, django, mongodb

I am a beginner and I haven't worked a lot with APIs and backend stuff.
I have a large set of data in JSON with about 100,000 records (say list of Users).

I want to implement RESTful API through which one can search for a particular record using one of the keys (say UserName).

The JSON file is nested to 2 levels. What would be the best way for implementing the above data set. Since the record is big I don't want any issues with the search time. I can have the following frameworks as I am proficient in JS and Python -

Use NodeJS and MongoDB (MongoDB has map/reduce for quick search I suppose)

Use Django with Rest Framework and Relational database.

Which one should I use for this project?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow try to check out this https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of the [Django Web framework](http://djangoproject.com) for the implementation of the user model and storage of data, and the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) plugin for everything that deals with API requests. This is my short reasoning:

- Django will deal with authentication, database models and queries which will probably save you a lot of time and it will help you produce good and safe code.
- The use of a relational database is recommended in this case as you seem to have a well structured dataset. In addition, 100.000 entries are actually a small enough dataset with which relational databases will be able to deal without any issues. In fact, even if it goes into the millions it wouldn't be a big deal.
- The REST framework will help you to quickly build an API that supports [pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) which is important if you're planning to return many entries at once. The pagination feature will allow you to just return a small set of values for each request, keeping the response time short and allowing the client to fetch more data (i.e. the next results page) if necessary.
- The REST framework also allows you to specify [search](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and [ordering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) attributes which the client will be able to access through GET parameters of your API.

All in all, I think using a framework like Django might feel like an overkill at first, but due to the great community support and large number of plugins it will enable you to write an API that works well and reliably in a relatively short time. To get started with Django, I highly recommend the [getting started with Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) guide.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.